# WW2-era bureaucrats escaping nuclear war into Lovecraftian dimension

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, nuclear-weapons

There was a short story I must have read before 2010, about a group of WW2 American bureaucrats who escaped from a nuclear world in their dimension, into a Lovecraftian dimension. The story ended with the protagonist realizing how unpleasant the new, unexplored dimension would be to live in.

Know what this could be?

Comment: Title says "escaping nuclear war", body says "escaped from a nuclear world". Is "world" a typo for "war"? The "dimension" the bureaucrats are escaping, is it **our** world or some fictional world? Our WW2 was non-nuclear until the last few days, and no American bureaucrats were under nuclear attack as far as I know. The story is alternate history, with lots of nukes thrown in WW2? The Germans got the bomb first? What sort of tech did they use to travel between dimensions?

Comment: This makes me think of the *Laundry Files* books by Charles Stross.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think this might be Charles Stross's "[A Colder War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Colder_War)", [available to read](http://www.infinityplus.co.uk/stories/colderwar.htm) linked from Wikipedia and the author's website.

> The main viewpoint character, Roger Jourgensen, is a CIA analyst who writes up a report on the state of both the U.S. and Soviet governments' occult research for incoming President Ronald Reagan. This report attracts the attention of "the Colonel" (implied to be Oliver North), who arranges for Jourgensen's transfer and for him to work on a variant of the Iran–Contra affair: secret dealings between the U.S. and Iran to counter Saddam Hussein's Iraq, frustrate the Soviet intervention in Afghanistan, as well as arrange the freeing of hostages in Lebanon.
>
> In the Cold War, the U.S. and NATO lag behind the Soviets in mastery of the dark arts, and rely on nuclear weapons as their main countermeasure. The Soviets gained their knowledge from Nazi Germany, which had moved a sleeping entity from an underwater city in the Baltic Sea; the entity is now contained at Chernobyl. They have also deployed "servitors", unstoppable robot-like beings found in the original Pabodie expedition. Satellite reconnaissance by the U.S. shows that the servitors may have been deployed in Afghanistan, which would violate a secret multinational treaty prohibiting the use of these alien entities in war to which even Adolf Hitler adhered. U.S. countermeasures include 300 megatons of nuclear weapons and a continuity of government base hundreds of light years from Earth, connected via a gate in Washington. The CIA also uses these gates to other planets as roundabout ways to transport drugs and arms to and from the Afghan mujahideen as part of Operation Cyclone.
>
> Stephen Jay Gould briefs the CIA on the evolutionary implications of the alien lifeforms, confirming they come from no Earthly source. Other nations emulate the superpowers; Iran and Israel covertly plan a joint nuclear defence against Iraq's attempts to open a gate to the stars. Eventually, the Colonel's dealings are leaked, and Jourgensen has to testify before a congressional committee. One congressman, horrified by the accounts of the Colonel's dabbling, inquires about the Great Filter: why no aliens have openly stopped by to visit humanity, and only relics and servants remain. He points out that meddling with relics of the Elder Ones would be a good explanation for why other intelligent life has been exterminated before it could visit.
>
> Saddam stabilises the gate of Yog-Sothoth, destroying opposing tribes in Iraq, causing Iran to retaliate with a nuclear attack. The timing unfortunately lines up with a joke by President Reagan; the Soviets and their leader Yegor Ligachev retaliate, with a nuclear war destroying the Middle East and much of the U.S. and Soviet Union. More worryingly, the entity behind the Soviet program, Cthulhu, has somehow been loosed; the U.S. nuclear strike does not appear to slow it down as it heads west across the Atlantic Ocean. Jourgensen and other U.S. personnel retreat to a hidden constructed colony on a distant dying planet, codenamed XK Masada. There, riven by phantom voices, Jourgensen contemplates suicide. He decides against it, as death would be no escape if – as he suspects – he has been devoured by Yog-Sothoth already.

It's not set during World War II, but the eldritch knowledge was acquired then, and otherwise, the plotline seems to fit with them being transported to another dimension to escape nuclear launches, and with the protagonist realizing that the solution may be worse than the problem.

> Roger looks at his cigarette disbelievingly: throws it far out into the night sky above the plain. He watches it fall until its ember is no longer visible. Then he gets up. For a long moment he stands poised on the edge of the cliff nerving himself, and thinking. Then he takes a step back, turns, and slowly makes his way back up the trail towards the redoubt on the plateau. If his analysis of the situation is wrong, at least he is still alive. And if he is right, dying would be no escape.
>
> He wonders why hell is so cold at this time of year.

Comment: It's [available online](http://www.infinityplus.co.uk/stories/colderwar.htm) (linked from the author's website).

Comment: Good reminder that this exists: I just went and read it again :) A darker outcome than the Laundry Files for sure!

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 Have you been keeping up with the Laundry Files so far?  In the series to date, humanity is *already* the proxy-war plaything of a number of the minor Old Ones, jockeying for position before the Great Old Ones (e.g. Cthulhu) cut loose.  I did mention on Charles Stross's blog that whilst Masquerade-type tropes are great, there's always the problem of what happens when you actually show the Big Bad, breaking continuity, and leading to the problem of "well it's bad, but it's not *that* bad".  Which is why Masquerade-type fiction tends not to break "normal" continuity.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 ... Charlie replied to me saying that he fully did intend to break the world (as the latest couple of books have indeed done), and that he had Case Nightmare Green (the rise of the Great Old Ones) mapped out.  The way he writes, I have no doubt that it could indeed be *that* bad.  And the way he's written Bob and Mo, the ongoing question of whether what's left will actually be human, or *something else* which kind of remembers what it was like to be human.

Comment: @Graham I like the way the Alfar civilisation's use of Geases and magic parallels the Black Chamber's approach to loyalty. The "Not so different" is very strong there. The implication is strongly that this structure is a likely outcome for the surviving humanity too.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots it's not actually _on_ the author's website, but linked from it (so no copyright issues there).

Comment: Also, a good review of the yarn at https://www.tor.com/2016/10/12/nuking-them-from-orbit-may-not-help-charlie-strosss-a-colder-war/

Comment: I wondered, when I read that story, whether the end of the story (quoted here) was supposed to mean that the people at the base had not *really* escaped, but had somehow been consumed by the Soviet entity, and were experiencing a false continued existence that was secretly "hell".

Comment: @tbrookside: That's on interpretation, but my read on it is that they indeed escaped Earth, but the place they landed in was indeed Hell.

Answer (score 1):

Stross's 'Laundry Files' novel [Atrocity Archives](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheJenniferMorgue) features nazis escaped to another dimension.

Also his novella [Missile Gap](https://subterraneanpress.com/magazine/spring_2007/fiction_missile_gap_by_charles_stross), where the world seems to be gathered into a cosmic petri dish.

BTW Charlie your 'buy my books' partnerId links are 404-ing

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please focus your post on a single answer and add details showing how good a match it is; you should read [answer].

Comment: :) And I'm really not certain how you plan on addressing Charles Stross on this page (or even where you're encountering these non-working links) as I don't think he hangs around here.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots links from his blog site 'buy my books' https://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/buy-my-books/buy-my-books-us.html